# TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj fetching data using Jquery Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

this is my code snippet

```
      jQuery('select[name="' + element + '"]').html('<option value="">Select</option>');
                jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
                    jQuery('select[name="' + element + '"]')
                    .append(jQuery("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", key)
                    .text(value));
                });
```

and this is the array that i am getting from response

```
   {"1":"470 - MAJOR JOINT REPLACEMENT OR REATTACHMENT OF LOWER EXTREMITY W\/O MCC","2":"885 - PSYCHOSES","3":"897 - ALCOHOL\/DRUG ABUSE OR DEPENDENCE W\/O REHABILITATION THERAPY W\/O MCC","4":"885 - PSYCHOSES","5":"470 - MAJOR JOINT REPLACEMENT OR REATTACHMENT OF LOWER EXTREMITY W\/O MCC"}
```

and i am getting this error, i dont know why i am getting this error **TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj**

**EDIT** : TO remove confusion i am posting the function with which i am sending request as follows:

```
        function  fetchValuesForDrgDefinition(url,drg) {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "json",
                    url: url,
                }).success(function(data) {
                    appendOptionsInSelectBox(drg,data);
                });

            }
```

Comment: where's the curly braces.?

Comment: well i thought it was common sense i just pasted the response, but if above makes it ambiguous i will place braces

Comment: I guess you are passing a string (JSON) instead of object. Try doing `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: How are you setting `data`? Are you parsing the JSON into an object?

Comment: well its simply returned using Json_Encode

Comment: If you are using ajax, you should post the ajax request code as well as you can probably just change the `dataType`. If not, you need to parse the json string.

Comment: On its own, I didn't have any problems with this code.  My guess is that the error is being caused by some code that wasn't included in the example. (http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/d3Bwg/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you set `dataType: 'json'` in your jQuery ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Try will work:

> var data = [
>       {val: 1, text: "One"},
>       {val: 2, text: "Two"}, ];
>
> $("#PoNo").append(function() {
>       return $.map(data, function(el, i) {
>           return '' + el.text + ''; 
>           // return $('', {val: el.val, text: el.text});
>       }); });